# OpenLayers.Format.WMTSCapabilities vs ol.source.WMTS

Tags: openlayers, wmts

Struggling with getting a WMTS layer working using OL2. I have it working with OL3 but unfortunately I'm working with legacy code and it needs to work on OL2.

**Using OL3 (working)**

```
var xml = '...';  // The get capabilities result   
var result = parser.read(xml);
var options = ol.source.WMTS.optionsFromCapabilities(result, {
    layer: 'XXX',
    matrixSet: 'default028mm'
});

var wmts = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.WMTS(options),
    extent: ol.proj.transformExtent([-3.867188, 55.850650, -2.548828, 56.170023], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')
});

map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM(),
            opacity: 1
        }),
        wmts
    ],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [62428.0, 7530366.0],
        zoom: 5
    })
});
```

**Using OL2 (not working)**

```
var xml = '...'; // The get capabilities result

var format = new OpenLayers.Format.WMTSCapabilities();

var capabilities = format.read(xml);
var layer = format.createLayer(capabilities, {
    maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-3.867188, 55.850650, -2.548828, 56.170023).transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    layer: "XXX",
    isBaseLayer: false
});
map.addLayer(layer);

var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
map.addLayer(osm);

map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(62428.0, 7530366.0), 7);
```

With OL2 the tile image requests are incorrect with minus values i.e. /0/**-284**/441.jpg

As far as I can see I am dealing with this in the same way for both OL2 & OL3.

Does anyone know the main differences between how this default behaviour is handled in the two different versions?